Проблема добавления/извлечения из ObjectPool
Создал ObjectPool на Unity для генерации мобов, но столкнулся с проблемой: весь скрипт отрабатывает штатно, кроме одной строчки, а именно добавление в пул предзагруженных объектов.
При предзагрузке пула, скрипт не может обработать добавление объекта в пул и выдает ошибку (создает объект на сцене, но не может добавить его в пул и скрыть), поэтому на сцене появляется один экземпляр и в консоль падает ошибка:
NRE (я знаю что это, но ссылка на экземпляр ведь указана в скобках?)
Строка 43, если кто-то будет копировать код:
_pool.Enqueue(item);
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace ObjectsPool
{
    public class PoolBase<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T> _preloadFunc;
        private readonly Action<T> _getAction;
        private readonly Action<T> _returnAction;

        private Queue<T> _pool;
        private List<T> _active = new();

        public PoolBase(Func<T> preloadFunc, Action<T> returnAction, Action<T> getAction, int preloadCount)
        {
            _preloadFunc = preloadFunc;
            _getAction = getAction;
            _returnAction = returnAction;
            if (preloadFunc == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError(message: "Preload function is null");
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < preloadCount; i++)

                Return(item: preloadFunc());

        }
        public T Get()
        {
            T item = _pool.Count > 0 ? _pool.Dequeue() : _preloadFunc();
            _getAction(item);
            _active.Add(item);

            return item;
        }

        public void Return(T item)
        {
            _pool.Enqueue(item);
            _returnAction(item);
            _active.Remove(item);
        }

        public void ReturnAll()
        {
            foreach (T item in _active.ToArray())
            { Return(item); }
        }
    }
}


Очевидно это оттого, что ссылка _pool не ссылается на объект. Создания соотв. объекта в коде не видно.

это скрипт конкретно пула, его применение находится в другом скрипте, который уже и создаёт/добавляет объекты. Но при предзагрузке проблема возникает именно здесь, в этой строке.
Каким образом здесь можно указать конкретный объект, если он создается из префаба и до инициализации в другом скрипте в Awake, его не существует?

Это не скрипт, а определение класса. Объект, на который ссылается _pool, не может быть создан ни в каком другом скрипте, так как у этого поля модификатор private и нет никакого сеттера. Заметьте, я пишу не про те объекты, которые будут хранится в коллекции, а про сам объект-коллекцию.

при создании экземпляра данного класса (де факто дочернего), разве не создается очередь, как в определении?

Благодаря вашему ответу нашел в чем была ошибка. Не могли бы вы оформить ваш комментарий как ответ?

Проблема оказалась в этой строке private Queue<T> _pool;
Пропустил создание новой очереди private Queue<T> _pool = new()
